# PHP Datetime diff output all in days, not month years and so on

Tags: php, datetime, diff

I got this code:

```
$EndDate = new DateTime($ArrayRand[$i]['comp_end']);

$interval = $DateIdag->diff($EndDate);
```

My echo:

```
echo $interval->format('%d dage %h timer');
```

The problem is, if the `$EndDate` is over 1 month, it only echo the days left, not days completely back. How can I accomplish this? That I takes all the days left, not month, years, only days and hours left do the event?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days and in format it is letter `a` - `Total number of days as a result of a DateTime::diff() or (unknown) otherwise` http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: check this [link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-calculate-real-differences-between-two-dates-or-timestamps/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
echo $interval->days . ' days';
```

or:

```
echo $interval->format('%a') . ' days';
```